# Delete the entire div including subdiv's on clicking the remove button

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to reactjs development and I'm trying real hard to delete the entire division including sub divisions on clicking "remove" button. The addition of entire div is working smoothly, but I am not sure how can I perform deletion of entire div on clicking remove button.

```
class Createloc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 1,
      rows: [],
    }
    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this)
    this.deleteRow = this.deleteRow.bind(this)
  }
  // divID = nextId();

  addRow() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
    console.log(`Increase count: ${this.state.count}`)
  };

  deleteRow(e) {
    // ==> not sure
    // console.log("delete");
  };

  addingDivs() {
    let count = this.state.count, uiItems = [];
    while (count--)
      uiItems.push(
        <div className="newHost" id={this.divID}>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Building Name" />
          </div>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" />
          </div>
          <div className="hostInput">
            <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={this.deleteRow}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    return uiItems;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <form className="form">
          <div className="addButton">
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addRow}>Add</button>
            {this.addingDivs()}
          </div>
        </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Createloc;
```

PS: I have not included the pseudo I tried to delete just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete the added row as a stack by applying below:

```
 deleteRow(e) {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 })
  };
```

Thanks!